# How can i get Details information from selected file?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, uri

I am choosing file using intent as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

and get the file `uri` as:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

now i want to know the following information of the file:

1. name of the file
2. size of the file
3. type of the file
4. date of creation

I have searched on Google and also in stackOverflow but found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `URI` to `file` and then get all the values, have look :

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        File file =new File(uri.getPath());
        int size = (int)file.length();
        String name = file.getName();
        String fileType= getMimeType(uri)

}

public static String getMimeType(String url) {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: probably because https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html and search for `getPath`